# Cypress : The Plugins file is missing or invalid

Tags: cypress

Every time when I open Cypress, I got this error. I troubleshoot but not able to solve the issue. I found the similar threads here but not helping really. Any would be appreciated.
index.js file: cypress\plugins\index.js

Image of error:
[image]

Comment: error image is attached.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have your project on OneDrive, but you cannot run Cypress from there.

Please trying moving your project to a local drive.

Comment: I moved to my local drive (C:\cypressdemo) still seeing the same error. Anything to check inside index.js file or support/commands.js or support/index.js?

Comment: What does the `cypress.json` config file have? Did you explicitly set any paths in there?

Comment: I ran this command: npm i cypress-plugin-snapshots -S and the snapshot error gone. Now, I am getting following Error: Cannot find module '@percy/cypress/task'

Comment: So, local drive version is working properly now - you just need to read up on how to install the plugins correctly.

Comment: can you point me to the right direction? I am still stuck here